# Is there a way to make a weathervane simulation

Tags: physics

I was wondering if a weathervane physic simulation was possible (i.e. a weathervane that is pushed by a wind). I can create something that looks a bit like it (thanks to Chris) but that is not entirely satisfying as the settings are pretty complicated, the hinge object needs to be tilted (?), the wind needs to be carefully placed, etc... (by the way, I've tried the wind *Tube* falloff option, instead of the *Sphere* option, isn't the wind *Tube* option supposed to create a wind effect within the tube area only? Doesn't seem to be the case...)

Result so far:

[image]

File: [image]

Comment: For the _Tube_ option, yes it is supposed to do that. The question is how you have set up the falloff... in my Blender it works.

Comment: If you've made it worked with the tube option (and no hinge tilt?) could you please share your file?

Comment: I'm sorry, if I had a solution I would write an answer... I usually don't work with hinge constraints. I use the falloff settings mostly when working with particles, and from them I could only say the _Tube_ falloff works. The thing is, with particles being blown around it is easy to see, I'm not even sure how it looks with a rigid body spinning on its axis.

Comment: Yes I'm not sure that it works as well with cloth or rigid body

Comment: If you want it to blow wind only in a limited tubular area, you have to set a _Radial_ > _Max Distance_ to ensure wind is not blowing outside of the tube with the set radius. I thought you want it to blow on one end of the cube for example. The problem is, the cube only starts spinning as soon as the hinge object is within the tube max distance.

Comment: Oh ok I understand why it didn't work, still not sure how to control the rotation and why the hinge needs to be tilted, which is annoying

Comment: And that's exactly the thing I have no experience with either, that's why I can only say, yes, _Tube_ falloff works but I can't answer your question.